# Copying a file to HDFS using julia language

Tags: hadoop, julia

I am having an issue now while copying a file to HDFS using Julia language.

Here is the log:

```
julia> cp("/etc/hosts",hostsFile)
ERROR: Associative collections only contain Pairs;
Either look for e.g. A=>B instead, or use the `keys` or `values`
function if you are looking for a key or value respectively.
in in at dict.jl:13
in _get at /home/bala/.julia/v0.4/Elly/src/rpc.jl:371
in call at /home/bala/.julia/v0.4/Elly/src/rpc.jl:786
in _write at /home/bala/.julia/v0.4/Elly/src/api_hdfs_io.jl:293
in write at /home/bala/.julia/v0.4/Elly/src/api_hdfs_io.jl:311
in cp at /home/bala/.julia/v0.4/Elly/src/api_hdfs_io.jl:376
```

Any clue will really help me to move forward.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you using HDFS.jl package? The signature for cp is: `cp(fs::HdfsFS, src::AbstractString, dst::AbstractString)` so you should first pass the handle to the file system, then source and destination (strings)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using Elly package with julia 0.4 version. The code I tried is listed below                                                                           Pkg.status()
Pkg.update()
Pkg.add("Elly")
using Elly
dfs = HDFSClient("photo-assess", 9000)
readdir(dfs)
cd(dfs,"user/bala/RDF_STORE")
hostsFile = HDFSFile(dfs,"hosts2.txt")
cp("/etc/hosts",hostsFile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there was a problem with the Elly package and hence contacted the contributor. Thanks to him, he fixed the issue in time and I then checkedout the latest Elly package. Its all started working now.